# How does NumberQ work

Tags: replacement

I want `Log[2 x / Pi]` to be expressed as `Log[2/Pi] + Log[x]`

so I make this replacement

```
Log[c__?NumberQ x] -> Log[c] + Log[x]
```

but it doesn't work.

Actually

```
MatchQ[2/Pi, c_?NumberQ]
>>> false
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compare documentation for [`NumberQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberQ.html) with that for [`NumericQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html)

```
?NumberQ
```

[image]

```
NumberQ /@ {2, 2., Pi, E}

(* {True, True, False, False} *)

?NumericQ
```

[image]

```
NumericQ /@ {2, 2., Pi, E}

(* {True, True, True, True} *)

Log[2 x/Pi] /. Log[num_?NumericQ sym_Symbol] :> Log[num] + Log[sym]

(* Log[2/π] + Log[x] *)
```

Note also use of [`PowerExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html)

```
Log[2 x/Pi] // PowerExpand

(* Log[2] - Log[π] + Log[x] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another approach -the canonical answer is the one by @Bob Hanlon.

### **You can use [`CoefficientList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html)**

```
coeflst = 
  Simplify@CoefficientList[FunctionExpand[Log[2 x/Pi]], Log[x]];
Expand[FromDigits[Reverse[coeflst], Log[x]]]
```

> [image: coef]